# how to get the returned URL from ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i'm trying to get only the returned URL from ajax request

like this

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType : "jsonp",
                    async: false,
                    url: $('#FaceBookProfileLink').attr('href'),

                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(jqXHR);
                        console.log(textStatus);
                        console.log(errorThrown);
                    }
                });
```

but i can't.

the returned URL showing in the console as js file but i can't get it

[image: the URL in console]

please any help and many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using 'GET' method, retrieve them with $_GET[], ie:

```
echo $_GET['code']
```

Comment: i'm trying to do this as ajax request so i don't have to reload the page the  $_GET will not work thank you for you answer

Comment: you'd like to get it in jquery like this? console.log(response.split('=')[1]);